# List of template function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

```
#include "PolygonFactory.h"

typedef Polygon *(*fp)(const Polygon &);

template<class T>
Polygon *PolygonFactory::checkPolygon(const Polygon &polygon) {
    if (T::canBeCreatedWith(polygon)) {
        return new T(polygon.getVertices());
    }

    return nullptr;
}

Polygon *PolygonFactory::makePolygon(const list<Point> &vertices) {
    Polygon polygon = Polygon(vertices);
    list<fp> list;
    list.push_back(&PolygonFactory::checkPolygon<Triangle>);

    //Some other code
}
```

Hello. I have some questions here.
I am trying to figure out how to create a list of pointers to a template function, but with the declaration of the function type.
What I'd like to do is, let's say, something like this:

```
list.push_back(&PolygonFactory::checkPolygon<Triangle>);
```

I already tried this but it's not working right now. There is clearly a problem with the typedef declaration.
Can someone please help me and explain whether and how it's possible or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that `checkPolygon` is not a free function but `fp` is. Don't use function pointers use `std::function`.

Comment: @imreal
Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Is `checkPolygon` `static` ?

Comment: Try changing the `typedef` for something like this `typedef std::function<Polygon*(const Polygon&)> fp`

Comment: Might have to `#include <functional>`

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it is